# how to keep form being displayed after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a small form and the submit is via AJAX. After submit, the php echo is comes in but the form is gone. But the form should stay on the page when the echo is being displayed. 
How can i do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subscribe_newsletter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#subscribe_newsletter').val($(this).val());
    var data = $("#subscribe").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'email_subscribe.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function() {
          $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);

        });
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="form" class="subscribe_wrapper"></div>
  <form id="subscribe" method="POST">
    <input name="email_subscribe" type="text" />
    <input class="subscribe_newsletter" id="subscribe_newsletter" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
```

This is the php file `email_subscribe.php`:

```
// subscribe 
if (isset($_POST['email_subscribe'])) {   
  $email_add = $_POST['email_subscribe'] . ',' . "\n";
  $store = file_put_contents('database-email.txt', $email_add, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
  if($store === false) {
    die('There was an error writing to this file');
  }
  else {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <?php echo $_POST['email_subscribe'] . 'is added to the list!'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```

So how can I ensure that the form stays visible after the request?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, you seem to be hiding the form yourself: `$("#subscribe").fadeOut(500).hide(...`

Comment: i did already disable this line but it didn't make sense...

Comment: @jeroen I'm pretty sure he didn't write the code

Comment: Also do NOT call anything in a form submit. It hides the form submit method

Comment: @derloopkat the button also has the class, so that shouldn't be a problem, what I don't understand is, if `.subscribe_wrapper` contains the form and already appears, why are you Fading it in? and why call `.show()` after `.fadeIn()`? Is the JavaScript code in another file or written inside a script tag?

Comment: @Mehdi Now i put the form out of the `subscribe_wrapper`. But what happens now: the form is hided now with: `style="display: none"`. Where is `display:none;` generated?

Comment: Well I don't know, is this your whole JS code? and you didn't answer me if the JS code is stored in a file or is inline?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
<input class="subscribe_newsletter" id="subscribe_newsletter" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
```

with this:

```
<button class="subscribe_newsletter" id="subscribe_newsletter" type="button">Subscribe</button>
```

The `type="button"` will make the form not submit

Comment: type="submit" may be causing unexpected behaviour

Comment: @thatoneguy unlikely - he preventDefault AND returns false :)

Comment: you are right. I must be blind for not noticing the **e.preventDefault()**. My solution was based on **e.preventDefault()** being missing.

Comment: Without `e.preventDefault();` the AJAX is not working. But i did remove `return false`. But nothing changes...In the form, the element `display:none;` is added. But where is it generated?

Comment: It is working now! I forgot to disable line `$("#subscribe").fadeOut(500).hide(function()`

Comment: next time when you want to send your form with ajax, don't put  a submit button in your form. and note that button elements inside <form></form> tags, acts as submit button by default. You should explicitly say your button is not a submit button by giving it a **type** attribute like this: **<button type="button" ...>**